# how to get url array after uploading multiple file to firebase storage in js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

how to get url array after uploading multiple files to firebase storage. i'm using the below code but it return metadatas array.

```
firebase.storage().ref().constructor.prototype.putFiles = function(files) { 
  var ref = this;
  return Promise.all(files.map(function(file) {
  return ref.child(file.name).put(file);
  }));
}

// use it!
firebase.storage().ref().putFiles(files).then(function(metadatas) {
 // Get an array of file metadata
 }).catch(function(error) {
 // If any task fails, handle this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to return the download URL *instead* of the metadata after uploading each file:

```
return Promise.all(files.map(function(file) {
  return ref.child(file.name).put(file).then(function() {
    return ref.child(file.name).getDownloadURL();
  })
}));
```