# upload multiple images to Cloud Storage through Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload multiple pictures to Cloud Storage through Firebase. I am using expo ImagePicker, which can take multiple images using the camera.

Here is code,

```
const [image, setImage] = useState([]);
const pickImageOnly = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 0.5,
    });
    
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setNextImg(true);
      setImage((images) => images.concat(result.uri));
    }
  };
```

Now, I am trying to store those images in the firestore database. However, only one image is stored in the database, Here is my try.

```
const uploadImage = async () => {
    for (let step = 0; step < image.length; step++) {
      const uploadUri = image[step];
      let filename = uploadUri.substring(uploadUri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  
      setUploading(true);
      setTransferred(0);
  
      const response = await fetch(uploadUri);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(`${user.email}/images/${filename}`)
      const task = storageRef.put(blob);
  
      // Set transferred state
      task.on('state_changed', (taskSnapshot) => {
        // console.log(
        //   `${taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred} transferred out of ${taskSnapshot.totalBytes}`,
        // );
    
        setTransferred(
          Math.round(taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred / taskSnapshot.totalBytes) *
          100,
        )
      })
      try {
    
        const ref = await task;
        const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL()
        setUploading(false);
        setImage(null);
        return url;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return null;
      }
      
    }
  }
```

How can I store all the images in the database?

Comment: You're trying to upload images to **Cloud Storage**, not to Cloud Firestore. I updated the tags and title to reflect this.

Comment: I don't think the `return url;` is: 1) actually waiting for the upload to complete, 2) waiting for **all** uploads to complete, which typically takes `Promise.all()`. For an example of this, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761825/upload-multiple-images-to-firebase-then-save-image-url-to-firestore/65762924#65762924 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59472622/how-to-get-url-array-after-uploading-multiple-file-to-firebase-storage-in-js/59473059#59473059

Comment: Hello, Frank, thanks a lot for your comments, I can't solve my issue. I am sure about  .put(file.uploadTask), uploadTask is clear for me. 
I am trying add 
```
.add({
        userId: user.uid,
        todos,
        value,
        postImg: imageUrl,
        postTime: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
      })
```

Comment: Don't post code blocks in comments please, as they become unreadable. Instead edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show the additional info.